# Passing templates without knowing their parameters

Tags: c++, templates, initializer-list

I am new to C++ and I unsure if I just don't know how to do this or if my approach is all wrong.

I have a Pipeline of processing Stages: each Stage takes data of a certain dimension, transforms it (which might change that dimension) and then calls the next stage on that data. Those dimensions are known at compile time and realized as template parameters. The method `setNext` is used define the following Stage.

```
template<unsigned int dimIn, unsigned int dimOut>
class Stage {
    void process(Data<dimIn> dataIn) {
        Data<dimOut> processed = // do something
        mNextStage.process(processed)
    }

    void setNext(Data<dimOut>) {
        // store pointer to next stage
    }
}
```

This works as expected. To group several stages and simplify their construction I want to create a Pipeline object to which different Stages can be passed. The problem is, that the input/output dimensions of the Stages is not equal, so I am unsure how to do this:

```
template<unsigned int firstDimIn, unsigned int firstDimOut>
class Pipeline {
    void addStage(Stage<?,?> stage) {
        // template parameters of stage are unknown
    }
}
```

The Pipeline is a template too, its parameters hold the input dimension of the first stage and output dimension of the last stage.

Example usage:

```
Stage<6,5> s1;
Stage<5,4> s2;
Stage<4,2> s3;

Pipeline<6,2> pipe;
pipe.addStage(s1);
pipe.addStage(s2);
pipe.addStage(s3);
```

Instead of building the Pipeline step by step with `.addStage()` a nice solution would also be to use initializer-lists:

```
Pipeline<6,2> pipe = {s1, s2, s3};
```

But I encounter the same problem there.

Comment: You could add template arguments to your `addStage` member function (`template<unsigned int X, unsigned int Y> void addStage(Stage<X,Y> stage)`) though you will likely find it challenging to store them in any sort of conventional container.

Comment: Make a template method `addStage`?

Comment: You need to make `addStage` a template as well.

Comment: Interesting, I did not know the "template member" concept yet. About storing them in a container: the stages are not stored as a container, instead each stage knows its successor. As for the initializer-list: any ideas how to do that?

Comment: If the pipeline of stages is known at compile time, you could also use a templated pipeline which has as template parameters all the stages instead of dimensions. Sort of `template<typename... Stages> class TemplatePipeline`

Comment: @Johannes You are describing a linked list of `Stage`s. You will still likely encounter challenges in forming this list. Specifically, consider what kind of object a `Stage` expects it's successor to be. If it's an object of the same type, that means a `Stage<6,5>` cannot refer to it's successor if it's a `Stage<5,4>` since they are different types. You may need to use a base type that all `Stage` inherit from and use polymorphism. You may bump into a similar problem when trying to let a `Pipeline` refer to the first element of your list.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux the templated pipeline would avoid this problem because it doesn't have to build any container, it could simply call `setNext` on each stage using the next template argument.

Comment: @MarcoPantaleoni I think Francois is right, this is indeed not as simple as I thought

Answer (score 4):

You can make a proxy and return a new type after every `add`. This can take advantage of the compile-time check of the dimension.

```
template<int NBeg, int NEnd> struct Stage {};

template<int N, int Saved>
struct PipelineBuilder {
    template<int M>
    PipelineBuilder<M, Saved>
    AddStage(Stage<N, M>) { return {}; }

    void done() {
        static_assert(Saved == N, "Incompatible dim");
    }
};

template<int NIn, int NOut>
struct Pipeline {
    PipelineBuilder<NIn, NOut> GetBuilder() { return {}; }
};

int main() {
    Stage<6,5> s1;
    Stage<5,4> s2;
    Stage<4,3> s3;

    Pipeline<6, 2> p;

    p
        .GetBuilder()
        .AddStage(s1)
        .AddStage(s2)
        .AddStage(s3)
        .done()
        ;
}
```